# Sharepoint update wizard stuck: The UPDATE permission was denied on the object 'Locks', database 'SharePoint_Config', schema 'dbo'

Tags: update

NOTE: This is another issue than my topic created before. This is another exception and I run the wizard with the install account.

I am using sp2013 foundation. I try update sp with this service pack: sharepointsp2013-kb2880551-fullfile-x64-en-us

I installed the service pack and finished. I did a reboot. After the reboot I start the wizard. I press a couple of times on next and then I saw a progress bar. It is stuck on step 9 of 10. I wait 4 hours and canceled the wizard. It is a small farm with 1 sharepoint server and 1 sql server. This sql server is also using for non sharepoint web applications. I found this error in the event viewer:

> Insufficient SQL database permissions for user 'Name:
>   MYCOMPANY\sa-sp-farm SID:
>   S-1-5-21-4150703077-982559751-1245044889-12028 ImpersonationLevel:
>   Impersonation' in database 'SharePoint_Config' on SQL Server instance
>   's096ap'. Additional error information from SQL Server is included
>   below.
>
> The UPDATE permission was denied on the object 'Locks', database
>   'SharePoint_Config', schema 'dbo'.

I found also this error:

> The Execute method of job definition
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPUpgradeJobDefinition (ID
>   fbedf013-0d07-4a92-b35a-59fd515181c2) threw an exception. More
>   information is included below.
>
> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

What is this?

Comment: restart the servers and re run the config wizard

Comment: I did, but it doesnt work.

Comment: could you please check the SQL logs, if their is any issue reported, give the SharePoint admin accounts full control on SQL server then try again

Comment: I give the farm account execture permissions and now it is working. thanks

Comment: great to see, finally its fixed...i think i cant add the answer to this question as it is duplicate. :(...no points for me